# converting text to datetime64 in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, date, datetime, numpy

I have numpy array of strings (p.s. why is string represented as object?!)

```
t = array(['21/02/2014 08:40:00 AM', '11/02/2014 10:50:00 PM',
           '07/04/2014 05:50:00 PM', '17/02/2014 10:20:00 PM',
           '07/03/2014 06:10:00 AM', '02/03/2014 12:25:00 PM',
           '05/02/2014 03:20:00 AM', '31/01/2014 12:30:00 AM',
           '28/02/2014 01:25:00 PM'], dtype=object)
```

I would like to convert it to numpy.datetime64 with day resolution, however the only solution I found is:

```
t = [datetime.strptime(tt,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p") for tt in t]
t = np.array(t,dtype='datetime64[us]').astype('datetime64[D]')
```

Can it get uglier than that? Why do I need to go through native Python list?
There must be another way...

By the way, I cannot find a way to plot an histogram of dates in numpy/pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format is the problem, `01/01/2015` is ambiguous, if it was in  ISO 8601 you could parse it directly using numpy, in your case since you only want the date then splitting and rearranging the data will be significantly faster:

```
t = np.array([datetime.strptime(d.split(None)[0], "%d/%m/%Y") 
for d in t],dtype='datetime64[us]').astype('datetime64[D]')
```

Some timings, first rearranging after parsing:

```
In [36]: %%timeit
from datetime import datetime
t = np.array(['21/02/2014 08:40:00', '11/02/2014 10:50:00 PM',
           '07/04/2014 05:50:00 PM', '17/02/2014 10:20:00 PM',
           '07/03/2014 06:10:00 AM', '02/03/2014 12:25:00 PM',
           '05/02/2014 03:20:00 AM', '31/01/2014 12:30:00 AM',
           '28/02/2014 01:25:00 PM']*10000)
t1 = np.array([np.datetime64("{}-{}-{}".format(c[:4], b, a)) for a, b, c in (s.split("/", 2) for s in t)])
....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop
```

Your code:

```
In [37]: %%timeit
from datetime import datetime
t = np.array(['21/02/2014 08:40:00 AM', '11/02/2014 10:50:00 PM',
           '07/04/2014 05:50:00 PM', '17/02/2014 10:20:00 PM',
           '07/03/2014 06:10:00 AM', '02/03/2014 12:25:00 PM',
           '05/02/2014 03:20:00 AM', '31/01/2014 12:30:00 AM',
           '28/02/2014 01:25:00 PM']*10000)
t = [datetime.strptime(tt,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p") for tt in t]
t = np.array(t,dtype='datetime64[us]').astype('datetime64[D]')
....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.56 s per loop
```

A dramatic difference with both giving the same result:

```
In [48]: t = np.array(['21/02/2014 08:40:00 AM', '11/02/2014 10:50:00 PM',
              '07/04/2014 05:50:00 PM', '17/02/2014 10:20:00 PM',
              '07/03/2014 06:10:00 AM', '02/03/2014 12:25:00 PM',
              '05/02/2014 03:20:00 AM', '31/01/2014 12:30:00 AM',
              '28/02/2014 01:25:00 PM'] * 10000)

In [49]: t1 = [datetime.strptime(tt,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p") for tt in t]
t1 = np.array(t1,dtype='datetime64[us]').astype('datetime64[D]')
   ....: 

In [50]: t2 = np.array([np.datetime64("{}-{}-{}".format(c[:4], b, a)) for a, b, c in (s.split("/", 2) for s in t)])

In [51]: (t1 == t2).all()
Out[51]: True
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic, but this only creates a "datetime.datetime" array and not a datetime64 array. p.s. it is very slow.

Comment: @HananShteingart, to get the rest is basically the same as your own code

Comment: Than that's not really a solution. Is there a way to format such strings directly to numpy?

Comment: @HananShteingart, I think you will find the edit is quite a bit faster