# How to get months from np.datetime64 object, NOT using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, date, datetime

I have an array like this one:

```
dt64 = array(['1970-01-01', '1970-01-02', '1970-02-03', '1970-02-04',
      '1970-03-05', '1970-03-06', '1970-04-07', '1970-04-08',
      '1970-05-09', '1970-05-10', '1970-06-11', '1970-06-12',
      '1970-07-13', '1970-07-14'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Now I want to plot some data associated with the single element of the array. In the figure I want to plot using matplotlib I need to draw a line that changes color for some months.

I want to draw the months mar to aug in orange and the others in blue.

I think I have to do two `plt.plot` lines, one for the orange line and one for the blue line.

My problem now is, I struggle to slice these datetime64 object in a way that returns the month to to compare them with the required months.

So far I have:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def md_plot(dt64=np.array, md=np.array):
    """Erzeugt Plot der Marsdistanz (y-Achse) zur Zeit (x-Achse)."""
    plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

    y, m, d = dt64.astype(int) // np.c_[[10000, 100, 1]] % np.c_[[10000, 100, 100]]
    dt64 = y.astype('U4').astype('M8') + (m-1).astype('m8[M]') + (d-1).astype('m8[D]')

    plt.plot(dt64, md, color='orange', label='Halbjahr der steigenden Temperaturen')
    plt.plot(dt64, md, color='blue', label='Halbjahr der fallenden Temperaturen')

    plt.xlabel("Zeit in Jahren\n")
    plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
    plt.ylabel("Marsdistanz in AE\n(1 AE = 149.597.870,7 km)")

plt.figure('global betrachtet...') # diesen Block ggf. auskommentieren
#plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
md_plot(master_array[:,0], master_array[:,1]) # Graph

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

This idea seemed to work, but won't work for a whole array:

```py
In [172]: dt64[0].astype(datetime.datetime).month
Out[172]: 1
```

I really try to avoid Pandas because I don't want to bloat my script when there is a way to get the task done by using the modules I am already using. I also read it would decrease the speed [here](https://www.frankanema.nl/2017/08/23/numpy-datetime-format/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441005/converting-a-string-to-np-array-with-datetime64-not-using-pandas/55441402?noredirect=1#comment97609386_55441402) solution fits the best for me:

`dt64[(dt64.astype('M8[M]') - dt64.astype('M8[Y]')).view(int) == 2]`

Thanks to Paul Panzer.

Answer (score 3):

If i understand you correctly this would do it:

```
[np.datetime64(i,'M') for i in dt64]
```

Comment: @Chistian This only generates a list of datetime64 objects like
```python
[numpy.datetime64('1895-09'),
 numpy.datetime64('1895-09'),
 numpy.datetime64('1895-09'),
 numpy.datetime64('1895-09'),
 ...]
```
How can I erase the year also to use the result for comparing to find the slices of ```dt64``` that I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Converting to python `datetime` in an intermediate step:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

datestrings = np.array(["18930201", "19840404"])
months = np.array([datetime.strptime(d, "%Y%m%d").month for d in datestrings])

print(months)

# out: [2 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

My version of numpy May be dated, but when I ran `np.datetime64(dt64[0])` I got numpy.datetime64('1970-01')

To get just the month (if that’s what you are looking for) try:

```
np.datetime_as_string(dt64[0]).split('-')[1]
```

Comment: Although I got this:
```
In [211]: int(np.datetime_as_string(dt64[0]).split('-')[1]) == 1
Out[211]: True 
```
I cannot get the intervals from the ```dt64``` array:
```python
In [221]: dt64[np.argwhere(int(np.datetime_as_string(dt64[i]).split('-')[1]) == 1)[0,0],0]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-221-f612585ccdf5>", line 1, in <module>
    dt64[np.argwhere(int(np.datetime_as_string(dt64[i]).split('-')[1]) == 1)[0,0],0]

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```